# Processos do node.js não estão sendo fechados

Tags: node.js, react, windows

Eu estava estudando react (utilizei o comando `npx create-react-app`) mas fechei o prompt que eu digitei o comando `npm start`. Quando vi os processos do meu computador, havia mais de 20 processos do node.

[image: processos do node mesmo eu não utilizando ele]

Tentei fechar os processos pelo "gerenciador de tarefas"> detalhes> finalizar processo. Depois tentei pelo prompt com `stop-process -name node`, mas não fechou nenhum processo.

Depois desinstalei o node e os processos ainda continuavam ativos.

Depois instalei o node novamente, e tentei executar o comando `npm --version` mas travou o prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que era só desinstalar o node.js e desligar o computador por um tempo (eu desinstalei e fui dormir) e os processos acabam de vez.